How to get the 'Label' name of 'Choice' type atrribute in Power Automate Flow?
How can I get the Label name of Choice type attributes when a new record is created?
While creating an Account I'm only getting the Values of Dropdown values instead of their labels. Also, for 'Single Select' Choice type I do get the Label as - "_new_currency_label".
Is there a way to get the Label names if the Choice type is 'Multi Select'??

I didn't get what exactly your are looking for.. label name of choice columns, are you looking for a selected value or something else?. Can please explain a bit more

Hi @SumitSingh, Please ignore, I got the point. Basically, my 'Cloud Flow' fetches the newly created records in Accounts entity. Suppose there was a Column of 'multiselect choice' type named 'city' and user selected 'Pune', 'Indore', 'Chennai' under that city column.
Now, the payload received by my Cloud flow will show city like -
"new_city": "1354,1352,1356"
where as I wanted to see the names(Labels) instead of IDs
